# Bad redirection in Liferay (HTTPS -> HTTP)

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, redirect, liferay

I'm experiencing some weird problems on Liferay.
At some point, I do a redirection, but I lose the "HTTPS" in the process.
Example, I am at an A page and I want to redirect to a B page. The URL is "https://web-site-name.com/page-a", after the redirection, the URL is "http://web-site-name.com/page-b", and the page is not found...

I'm using Liferay 6.1.2 and the lines which are doing the redirection is (in a ManagedBean) :

```
ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
context.redirect(url);
```

One important precision : the same code is working fine in another platform (which contains also a URL with "HTTPS"). So I'm thinking that the problem might come from the configuration of Liferay, rather than code itself.

Does anyone know where this could come from ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: how do you get `url` (the parameter for your `redirect(url)` call? What's its value?

Comment: May be you can check other properties in portal.properties that start with: `web.server.*`

Comment: @OlafKock: I put the URL of the Liferay page directly. In the example I gave, this would be a value of "page-b".

Comment: @PrakashK: I don't have any properties in portal.properties except 'login.events.post'. And I don't think the problem lays here, because everything works fine in my local platform (where the URL is localhost:8080) and it doesn't work in the Prod environment...

Comment: the `page-b` URL seems to be with `http` and what I meant was that you can try out the properties from portal.properties in your portal-ext.properties.

Comment: @PrakashK actually the page-b has a URL with https (like all other pages). After the redirection is made, the URL looses its "HTTPS" which makes a 404 error. If I change manually the URL to add "https" to it, it works fine. But it's the redirection that's making all the mess...